# best use of survey data

Tags: survey, reliability, censoring

So - I am trying to decide which resident to promote. Using their "Performance" as one metric (about 50% of their entire score) My idea was to normalize their survey score and then use that score in their overall total rank.

I realized I might have a problem.

The scoring is 1-10 from 14 reviewers. My plan was to use the median to decrease some potentially biased outlier results.

I really am trying to be fair to all these hard-working people, so getting this right is important to me. Some reviewers gave no score (because they didnt work with that person) and thus missing data exists. That might give me trouble with interobserver reliability. There might be issues with right censoring too?

Slight differences might mean the difference between job and no job.

Dashes mean missing data.
Each column is the same reviewer

```
Resident 1:  
 9  7  6  7  8  -  6  7  4  6  2  5  6  7
Resident 2:
10  7  8 10  8  8 10  8 10  9 10  6  8  9
Resident 3
 9  7  6  -  8  -  8  6  7  6  4  7  8  7 
Resident 4
 -  8  8  -  7  7  4  7  3  8  - 10
Resident 5
 8  9  7  -  9  9 10  8 10  9  8  4  5  8
```

Am I overthinking this?

Comment: I tried to format your Question for readability. Why does Resident 4 have only 12 entries? Are the 14 reviewers listed in the same order otherwise? If so, Rv 2 seems too hard to please and Rv 11 seems to have strong opinions. How to deal with missing observations depends on reasons for no opinion. Are missing observations due to no info, inattention, unwillingness to give bad score, ...? // Maybe you are 'underthinking' this. IMHO, residents should not be willing to be judged by such sketchy opinion data. // If you had complete data I might suggest using Friedman test with reviewers as blocks.

Comment: Not all reviewers worked with all residents. 
And this isn’t the only piece of data to be used!

Comment: What about the 12 reviews for Resident 4? Missing dashes? Do columns correspond to reviewers throughout? **Please edit your question so that your meaning is clear.** In your Comment you speak of other into, but in your Question you say, "Slight differences might mean the difference between job and no job." So I am confused about the weight these data will have.  // If columns do corresp to reviewers, then one method, among many, of imputing values for missing data would be to go halfway between row median and column median, moving toward grand median (as needed) to get integer.